# How to find the file name and size of the file from fsimage?

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I am trying to find the files which are less than block size in HDFS.

By using OIV i converted the fsimage into text file with delimiters like below.

`hdfs oiv_legacy -i /tmp/fsimage -o /tmp/fsimage_$RUNDATE/fsimage.txt -p Delimited -delimiter '@'`

Since fsimage has lot of data. From this how to find the file name and file size of each and every file in HDFS.

Can anyone please help.

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at scripts at the end of this [documentation](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HdfsImageViewer.html).

Starting from:

```
A = LOAD '$inputFile' USING PigStorage('\t') AS (path:chararray,
                                                replication:int,
                                                modTime:chararray,
                                                accessTime:chararray,
                                                blockSize:long,
                                                numBlocks:int,
                                                fileSize:long,
                                                NamespaceQuota:int,
                                                DiskspaceQuota:int,
                                                perms:chararray,
                                                username:chararray,
                                                groupname:chararray);

-- Grab the pathname and filesize
B = FOREACH A generate path, fileSize;

-- Save results
STORE B INTO '$outputFile';
```

Comment: Thanks for the help @ravwojdyla

Answer (score 0):

```
hadoop fs -find /tmp/fsimage size 64 -print
```

Note:I am using MapR Hadoop.The syntax might wary if its Cloudera,Hortonworks.

Comment: I guess in Cloudera and hortonworks distribution we don't have find option. 

Please correct me if i am wrong..